# More on ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, awt

I have a final coming up and one of the points my professor stressed was ComboBoxes. I already finished a homework assignment, which I also posted as a question through here and I understand it. He wants us to follow this pattern: [ComboBox code correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458587/combobox-code-correct).

Now, I started looking through other problems for own practice and I ran into some trouble. It is kind of like my homework assignment but with more to it. The question:

> A university has the following dormitories:
>
> - Allan Hall: $1,500 per semester
> - Pike Hall: $1,600 per semester
> - Fathering Hall: $1,200 per semester
> - University Suites: $1,800
>
> The university also offers the following meal plans:
>
> - 7 meals per week: $560 pr semester
> - 14 meals per week: $ 1,095
> - Unlimited meals: $1,800 per semester
>
> Create an application with 2 `ComboBox`es. One should hold the names of the dorms and
>   the other should hold the meal plans. The user should select a dorm and a meal plan 
>   and the application should show the total charges.

I started to write some code, but I'm not sure how to put two combo boxes one right after the other, and then how to create an "Calculate" button with a separate `ActionListener` for that, as well.

Here is the code; I know it's a mess. Can anyone show me how to write this correctly? I just want to be prepared. Please bear with me and thank you for your patience and help. My code (I'll put 4 `****` on parts of the code where the compiler came up red):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DormAndMealPlanCalc extends JFrame
{


    private JPanel dormPanel;
    private JPanel selectedDormPanel;
    private JComboBox DormBox;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField selectedDorm;


    private String[] dorm = {"Allen Hall: $1,500 per semester","Pike Hall: $1,100 per" +
    "semester","Fathering Hall: 1,200 per semester","Universty Suites: $1,800"};

    public void ComboBoxWindow1()
    {

        **super("Dorm plan");** wrong placement?

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        buildDormPanel();
        **buildSelectedDormPanel;** Variable error

        add(dormPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(selectedDormPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildDormPanel()
    {
        dormPanel = new JPanel();

        DormBox = new JComboBox(dorm);
        DormBox.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener());
        dormPanel.add(DormBox);
    }

    private void buildSelectedDormPanel()
    {

        selectedDormPanel = new JPanel();

        label = new JLabel("You selected: ");

        selectedDorm = new JTextField(10);
        selectedDorm.setEditable(false);

        selectedDormPanel.add(label);
        selectedDormPanel.add(selectedDorm);
    }

    private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String selection = (String) DormBox.getSelectedItem();
            selectedDorm.setText(selection);
        }
    }

    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        **new ComboBoxWindow2();**
    }

}

private JPanel mealPanel;
private JPanel selectedMealPanel;
private JComboBox MealBox;
private JLabel label1;
private JTextField selectedMeal;
private JButton calcbutton;

private String[] Meal = {"7 meals per week: $560 per semester","14 meals per week:" +
"$1,095 per semester","Unlimited meals: $1,500 per semester"};

public void ComboBoxWindow()
{

    **super("Meal plan");**

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    buildMealPanel();
    **BuildselectedMealPanel;** variable problem

    add(mealPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(selectedMealPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

private void buildMealPanel()
{
    mealPanel = new JPanel();

    MealBox = new JComboBox(meal);
    MealBox.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener());
    mealPanel.add(MealBox);
    **calcbutton = new JButton("Calculate");** syntax/token error
}
calacbutton.addActionListener(new calcbuttonListener);


private void buildSelectedMealPanel()
{

    selectedMealPanel = new JPanel();

    label = new JLabel("You selected: ");

    selectedMeal = new JTextField(10);
    selectedMeal.setEditable(false);

    selectedMealPanel.add(label);
    selectedMealPanel.add(selectedDorm);
}

private class ComboBoxListener1 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String str;
        String selection = (String) DormBox.getSelectedItem();
        selectedDorm.setText(selection);
        **JOptionPane.showMessageDialog('Total is' + dorm + meal);** argument error
    }
}}
```

Comment: **Hint:** You can define more than Combo Box for a Swing form.  Just duplicate what you did for the first combo box, but use a different drop down data list and give the combo box a different name.

Comment: Don't forget to add the [tag:homework] tag for homework questions.

Answer (score 4):

OP's code is not a valid Java, no way to make it work without first explaining how to code in OOP.

Lots of trivial errors.

1) no () after function call

`buildSelectedDormPanel;` -> `buildSelectedDormPanel();`

2) mistaken methods for classes/c-tors

`public void ComboBoxWindow1() {`

should be, for example

```
class ComboBoxWindow1 extends JFrame { 
  public void ComboBoxWindow1() {
```

etc, or even use anonymous class overrides, i.e.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame() {
```

etc.

3) ComboBox is a generic type, so please do NOT use the raw version - use ComboBox<String> instead

4) add @Override annotations to your code where needed

5) watch the case of your spelling... you mix lowerCase with lowercase and Lowercase

6) fix your parentheses (not only round, but curly too are misplaced all over your code)

7) you mistake "" for Strings with '' for chars

8) if you wish to comment your code (i.e. errors in your code, use the COMMENT /* */ or //, not some asterisks I have to delete before even trying to format your code properly,

9) there are too many gaps and errors, some unused variables, some fields (global vars? can't guess the intent) without any clear class attachment - all in all, fixing the code is per se impossible -

10) (trolling follows) you seem like you realized you haven't learned enough and the end of semester is near, so you tried to do your homework, produced some broken/illegible code, went panicky with no way to fix it and THEN you realized there's StackOverflow. Bad puppy, no bone.

11) code after fixing the most obvious errors [note that the code has no effect due to empty main()]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DormAndMealPlanCalc extends JFrame {
  private JPanel dormPanel;
  private JPanel selectedDormPanel;
  private JComboBox<String> DormBox;
  private JLabel label;
  private JTextField selectedDorm;
  private String[] dorm = { "Allen Hall: $1,500 per semester", "Pike Hall: $1,100 per"
    + "semester", "Fathering Hall: 1,200 per semester", "Universty Suites: $1,800" };

  protected class ComboBoxWindow1 extends JFrame {
    protected ComboBoxWindow1() {
      super( "Dorm plan" );
      setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
      buildDormPanel();
      buildSelectedDormPanel();
      add( dormPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
      add( selectedDormPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
      pack();
      setVisible( true );
    }
  }

  private void buildDormPanel() {
    dormPanel = new JPanel();
    DormBox = new JComboBox<>( dorm );
    DormBox.addActionListener( new ComboBoxListener() );
    dormPanel.add( DormBox );
  }

  private void buildSelectedDormPanel() {
    selectedDormPanel = new JPanel();
    label = new JLabel( "You selected: " );
    selectedDorm = new JTextField( 10 );
    selectedDorm.setEditable( false );
    selectedDormPanel.add( label );
    selectedDormPanel.add( selectedDorm );
  }

  private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
      String selection = (String) DormBox.getSelectedItem();
      selectedDorm.setText( selection );
    }
  }
  private JPanel mealPanel;
  private JPanel selectedMealPanel;
  private JComboBox<String> mealBox;
  private JLabel label1;
  private JTextField selectedMeal;
  private JButton calcbutton;
  private String[] meal = { "7 meals per week: $560 per semester",
    "14 meals per week: $1,095 per semester",
    "Unlimited meals: $1,500 per semester"
  };

  protected class ComboBoxWindow2 extends JFrame {
    protected ComboBoxWindow2() {
      super( "Meal plan" );
      setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

      setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

      buildMealPanel();
      buildSelectedMealPanel();
      add( mealPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
      add( selectedMealPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

      pack();
      setVisible( true );
    }
  }

  private void buildMealPanel() {
    mealPanel = new JPanel();
    mealBox = new JComboBox<>( meal );
    mealBox.addActionListener( new ComboBoxListener() );
    mealPanel.add( mealBox );
    calcbutton = new JButton( "Calculate" );
    calcbutton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Not supported yet." );
      }
    } );
  }

  private void buildSelectedMealPanel() {
    selectedMealPanel = new JPanel();
    label = new JLabel( "You selected: " );
    selectedMeal = new JTextField( 10 );
    selectedMeal.setEditable( false );
    selectedMealPanel.add( label );
    selectedMealPanel.add( selectedDorm );
  }

  private class ComboBoxListener1 implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
      String selection = (String) DormBox.getSelectedItem();
      selectedDorm.setText( selection );
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Total is" + dorm + meal );
    }
  }

  static public void main( String[] args ) {
    // do your thing
  }
}
```

TL;DR - please do your learning first, coding later.

Comment: how is dorm and meal being added in actionPerformed? aren't they string arrays.

Comment: please read before asking: "11) code after fixing the most obvious errors", "most obvious" means "most obvious", not "ALL" - "9) (...) all in all, fixing the code is per se impossible" - I'm not into guessing WHAT OP HAS IN MIND, since I can't read mind by my current means. I think that it's more important to learn these kids HOW TO CODE, than to supply them with complete homework answers. See my comment to your reply.